# How to run Nuitka on macOS

Tags: python, dylib, install-name-tool, nuitka

I am trying to run [Nuitka](http://nuitka.net/), just to test it, on a very basic Python script.
Unfortunately, I get an error I cannot properly understand.

```
$ nuitka-run dice_test.py                                                                                                                 
Nuitka:WARNING:The version '3.6' is not currently supported. Expect problems.
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/install_name_tool: more than one input file specified (libpython3.6m.dylib and --change)
Usage: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/install_name_tool [-change old new] ... [-rpath old new] ... [-add_rpath new] ... [-delete_rpath old] ... [-id name] input
Error, call to 'install_name_tool' to fix Python library path failed.
```

**What is the problem here? How to solve it?**

Some extra info:

```
# xxx @ yyy in ~/scripts on git:master x [11:53:39] C:1
$ locate libpython3.6m.dylib
/Users/xxx/homebrew/Cellar/python3/3.6.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/libpython3.6m.dylib
/Users/xxx/homebrew/Cellar/python3/3.6.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-darwin/libpython3.6m.dylib
/Users/xxx/homebrew/Cellar/python3/3.6.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/libpython3.6m.dylib
/Users/xxx/homebrew/Cellar/python3/3.6.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-darwin/libpython3.6m.dylib
/Users/xxx/homebrew/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/libpython3.6m.dylib
/Users/xxx/homebrew/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-darwin/libpython3.6m.dylib
/Users/xxx/homebrew/Cellar/python3/3.6.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/libpython3.6m.dylib
/Users/xxx/homebrew/Cellar/python3/3.6.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-darwin/libpython3.6m.dylib
/Users/xxx/homebrew/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/libpython3.6m.dylib
/Users/xxx/homebrew/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-darwin/libpython3.6m.dylib
/Users/xxx/homebrew/Cellar/python3/3.6.4_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/libpython3.6m.dylib
/Users/xxx/homebrew/Cellar/python3/3.6.4_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-darwin/libpython3.6m.dylib
/Users/xxx/miniconda3/lib/libpython3.6m.dylib
/Users/xxx/miniconda3/pkgs/python-3.6.3-h5ce8c04_4/lib/libpython3.6m.dylib
/Users/xxx/miniconda3/pkgs/python-3.6.3-h6804ab2_0/lib/libpython3.6m.dylib

# xxx @ yyy in ~/scripts on git:master x [11:53:49] 
$ which nuitka
/Users/xxx/miniconda3/bin/nuitka

# xxx @ yyy in ~ [12:16:56] 
$ which python
/Users/xxx/miniconda3/bin/python

# xxx @ yyy in ~ [12:17:05] 
$ python --version
Python 3.6.3 :: Anaconda, Inc.
```

I tried `install_name_tool -id "@loader_path/Users/xxx/miniconda3/lib/libpython3.6m.dylib" libpython3.6m.dylib` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try on bare Python. Nuitka appears to have difficulty to handle virtual environment like Anaconda in my humble experience.